# Path suddenly gets backslashed

Tags: python, windows, file, path, size

I'm trying to get the function to get the directory size.

```
def fsize(path, returntype='b'):
    size = 0
    if isdir(path):
        for root, dirs, files in walk(path):
            for file in files:
                size += getsize(join(path,file))

    else:
        print abspath(path)
        size = getsize(abspath(path))

    if returntype != 'b':
        return convert_size(size, returntype)
    return size

path = r"D:\Library\Daniel's_Books"

print fsize(path, 'm')
```

and I get this funny error:

```
size = getsize(abspath(path))
File "C:\Python27\lib\genericpath.py", line 49, in getsize
return os.stat(filename).st_size
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: "D:\\Library\\Daniel's_Books\\cover.jpg"
D:\Library\Daniel's_Books\cover.jpg
```

why does it backslash the backslashes?
and how can I fix the error?

Comment: I am unsure why it would add additional \. But have you tried to use "/" instead? It usually works far better for paths, with most libraries and languages.

Comment: yep, returns exactly the same thing. exactly.

Comment: Sounds like windows vista/7 and a permission problem, since you are trying to access files outside your userdir...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concerning your first question

> why does it backslash the backslashes?

It is just a matter of display. As `\` is the escape character, you would give strings with `\`s inside either as `r'\'` or as `'\\'`. And exactly this way it is displayed as well, in other words: exactly as it was retured by [the `repr()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr).

BTW: Your

```
path = "D:\Library\Daniel's_Books"
```

is problematic due to the same reasons: it only works because `\D` and `\L` are no valid escapes. You would better write it as

```
path = r"D:\Library\Daniel's_Books"
```

as a raw string or

```
path = "D:\\Library\\Daniel's_Books"
```

as a string with properly escaped `\`s.

---

Your second question, however,

> and how can I fix the error?

is a little bit trickier.

I think you have a problem with multiple recursion: On one hand, the `walk()` completely walks through the tree. So from the 2nd level on, `join(path,file)` is wrong, you should replace `path` with `root`. On the other hand, you call `fsize()` recursively, which might lead to duplication of files.

Assume you have the following tree:

```
.
+- A
|  +- a
|  +- b
+- B
|  +- a
|  +- b
+- a
+- b
```

`os.walk()` traverses the given tree by yielding `root, dirs, files` for every directory level.

In this example, it will yield

```
'.', ['A', 'B'], ['a', 'b']
'.\\A', [], ['a', 'b']
'.\\B', [], ['a', 'b']
```

So `root` contains the current processing directory where the `files` reside in.

I suppose your `cover.jpg` resides in a subdirectory of `Daniel's_Books`, not in this directory itself. Combining it with the correct directory will make it be found.

Comment: Didn't fix the problem. also; I tried it before asking on SOF, I always research my questions before posting :)

Comment: Which problem? You wanted to know why there are pairs of `\`, and I answered this. What did I miss?

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough, I wanted to know how to eliminate the \\ so it could complete the os.stat(path).st_size function.

Comment: You don't want to elimitate them, they are just a matter of display. Instead, see my edit.